# Resizing ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble with a boxplot I created in ggplot2.

The x-axis is not displaying the four labels below each boxplot.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(my.data, aes(x=as.factor(laser), y=response.rate, fill=laser)) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.size = 3) + 
      guides(fill=FALSE)+ylab("Response Rate") + xlab("Laser Type")+
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels=c("CO2", "Er:Glass", "Diode", "PDL"))
```

Here is the result of the plot:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think getting rid of `breaks=c(1,2,3,4)` (which, for future reference, you can shorten to `breaks=1:4`) will solve your problem.

Comment: The breaks in a discrete scale don't have numerical values, but take the names of the categories. For example, try this with the built-in `iris` data frame: `ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("setosa"))` or `ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:3)`